# Measure of set satisfying acute version of AM/GM

Tags: inequality

Let $N>2$ be integer. Take a $N$ real numbers $x[k] \in [0,1]$. By the *AMGM* inequality we have that their geometric mean is less or equal to their sum divided by $N$. 
My question is: what is the measure in $\mathbb{R}^N$ of those $x$'s that satisfy this inequality only the sum is divided by $2^N$ rather $N$?

Note that for N=3, it is equivalent to asking how many numbers satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: So clarify, you want to know $\mu(A)$ where

$$A = \left\{ x \in [0,1]^n \ \Big| \ \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{2^n} > \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} \right\}$$ 
Correct?

Comment: right, correct.